# own counter in data with databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, doctrine

```
id | num | text
1  | a   | sdfsdf
2  | a   | sdfsdf
3  | b   | sdfsdf
4  | c   | sdfsdf
5  | a   | sdfsdf
6  | b   | sdfsdf
7  | a   | sdfsdf
8  | c   | sdfsdf
```

i make query where **num = a** and orderBy **ID DESC** and i have:

```
id | num | text
7  | a   | sdfsdf
5  | a   | sdfsdf
2  | a   | sdfsdf
1  | a   | sdfsdf
```

i would like add for this own counter:

```
count | id | num | text
  4   | 7  | a   | sdfsdf
  3   | 5  | a   | sdfsdf
  2   | 2  | a   | sdfsdf
  1   | 1  | a   | sdfsdf
```

i get data with foreach PHP:

```
foreach ($data as $i => $dat) {
   echo $dat->id . $dat->num . $dat->text;
}
```

i would like somethings:

```
foreach ($data as $i => $dat) {
   echo $i . $dat->id . $dat->num . $dat->text;
}
```

but $i in the opposite direction

Comment: You can always get the opposite of `$i` by subtracting it from from the total count: `$opp = count($data) - $i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$count = count($data);
foreach ($data as $i => $dat) {
   echo ($count - $i) . $dat->id . $dat->num . $dat->text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP:

```
$i = count($data);
foreach ($data as $dat) {
    echo $i . $dat->id . $dat->num . $dat->text;
    $i--;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You know, you can solve that in your SQL query. This is a sample which a ran against a production Redmine DB instance (MySQL):

```
select @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number, issues.*
from issues, (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
where project_id = 7
and tracker_id = 3
order by 1 desc
```